# Is there really no way to forcefully kill a Thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

**Intro:**

Since `Thread.stop()` is deprecated the only way (as far as I know) to `stop` a Thread is to interrupt it.

The javadoc says, that interrupting a Thread means, that `the thread's interrupt status will be set`.

But doesn't that mean, that a Thread that is ignoring the interrupt flag will never terminate? I guess in most cases the application developer is also developing the Runnable, that is executed inside the Thread. So ignoring the interrupt flag is basically his own fault and I am totaly fine with this.

**But:**

What about the Edge case? What about Applications, that use a custom plugin mechanism for example.
Maybe you want to load a jar and let in run inside a newly created thread. Then the application itself loses all the power to manage the thread. It totally depends on the goodwill of the plugin developer, that he or she provides some way to stop the code (using the Reflection API and custom Annotations or whatever).

I also have other examples in mind, where it might be necessary to kill a Thread.

**My Conclusion**

I am totally aware why killing a Thread using `Thread.stop` is not the best idea. But I am kind of confused, why this option should be removed completely. I also had a look inside the concurrent API and I couldn't find a stop equivalent there neither.

Please share your thoughts about this.

Comment: You could provide the developer of the underlying running process with some kind of class that has a cancel state. Something like a CancellableRunnable class or something. By having a state inside the class you could have more control over when and how the thread stops. Of course it wouldnt necessarily be "instant", but it would definitely give you a lot of control. And you would also have to specify exit points where the code quits if it has been cancelled, but if you want control you'd need that regardless

Comment: Of course. There are solutions like this. My question is more about the disempowerment of the main thread. I just don't understand why the main thread of my application must not have the power to manage its childs. This was just one example, that came in my mind quickly.

Comment: The exact reasoning behind it is explained pretty clearly over here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Comment: I am also aware about that article.
As I said, I know about the problems of Thread.stop().
Just because it is a bad way to do it and could result in side effects isn't a reason to forbid it completely.

If I know, what I am doing, then it should be possible for me to delete kill a thread imo.

Comment: I mean, thats entirely what "deprecated" means. It means that it is discouraged from use. Since it's dangerous the people making Java don't recommend you use Thread.stop. They aren't forbidding it completely, they are just putting very big "WARNING" signs around it. I personally feel like, whatever you're making, there's a better way of doing it than using Thread.stop

Comment: Re, "Maybe you want to load a jar and let in run inside a newly created thread." Running foreign code is risky. There are various ways you can mitigate the risk ranging from the extreme (e.g., run it on a different, physical computer that has limited ability to communicate with any system that you think is important), to no mitigation at all (e.g., just fire it up in a new thread.) If you choose to just fire up a new thread, then you are choosing to grant a potential adversary _all_ of the privileges of the program that loads and runs the Jar.

Comment: @SolomonSlow please don't focus on this example. As I already said, it was the first thing, that came to my mind. And maybe not the best example ;)
Thanks for your reply anyway.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there really no way to forcefully kill a Thread in Java?

There is really no way **safe** way to forcefully kill a single Thread in Java.

`Thread.stop()` has been deprecated since Java 1.2 because it is inherently unsafe.

Some of the related methods have actually been removed, but `countFrames()`, `pause()`, `resume()` and `stop()` are still there.

It would be really nice if there was a **safe** way to stop a thread that isn't cooperating, but the Java designers realized a long time ago that `Thread.stop`:

1. potentially leaves objects in an indeterminate state, and
2. potentially leaves other threads waiting for notifications and condition variable changes that will never happen.

These mean that stopping a thread is liable to cause the rest of the application to behave unpredictably.  Furthermore, designing an application to recover from a stopped thread is (in general) impractical.

Unfortunately, there really is *no solution* to this in the confines of the Java thread model.

(You would need an alternative model where threads can only communicate by passing messages, and cannot share mutable state.  You could then code an application to be resilient in the face of threads being stopped or crashing.  However, this change would require a rewrite of the vast majority of existing Java code.  It was not possible in 1998.  It is even less possible now.)

For more details on the reasons for deprecation, read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html) and [Java Thread primitive deprecation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) technical note.

---

> But doesn't that mean, that a Thread that is ignoring the interrupt flag will never terminate?

Correct<sup>1</sup>.  That is a bug, either:

- in the code that is not paying attention to the flag, or
- in the application that allows *untrustworthy* plugin code (that ignores the flag) to run.

<sup>1 - But not completely correct.  The application could also call `System.exit` if a thread refused to die, or it could rely on an external monitor or human intervention: `^C`, `kill -9`.  This is how you would deal with the problem *in practice*.</sup>

---

> I am also aware about that article. As I said, I know about the problems of `Thread.stop()`. Just because it is a bad way to do it and could result in side effects isn't a reason to forbid it completely.

It is not completely forbidden.  It is deprecated.

Treat it as *very strong* advice.

Comment: *"It is not completely forbidden. It is deprecated."* —
And I'm pretty sure it hasn't been removed in all this time simply because there is no alternative.

Comment: There almost always is an alternative.

Comment: "It is not completely forbidden. It is deprecated." -- sure. But I understand a deprecated feature as a feature, that may be removed in the near feature. And I don't want it to be removed.

What about Threads that work on a completely separated set of values?
`stopping` this Thread would never result in having problems in the main thread.

I read both, the javadoc and the primitive description. As I said, I completely understand, why `stopping` is mostly bad. But mostly is not always and there are scenarios where `stopping` may be the only way.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation regarding the Thread Model and your opinion on the topic.

Comment: @GAlexMES: Yes, stopping certain threads can be safe. However, for this, you must know what the thread is doing and how it is doing it, i.e. basically you must have written its routine yourself. (In this case you could also write a different stopping mechanism, e.g. make the thread check variable `boolean stopped` every loop.) But there is no way to safely stop a "blackbox" thread.

Comment: @doublep yeah I am totally with you. But: Even when I am the developer of the thread. Polling a flag is a shitty solution. What if your Thread is a bit more complex and not just a loop? I don't want to poll that flag at `n` different places.
You are right. With the current Thread Model there is no way to safely stop a Thread.
But why is deprecating the only way to unsafely stop that Thread better then providing a better Thread Model?

Comment: I'm pretty sure switching to a different thread model that wouldn't be affected is outright impossible without rendering 95% of existing code invalid.

Comment: *"But why is deprecating the only way to unsafely stop that Thread better then providing a better Thread Model?"* - The first way is regrettable: the second way is impossible.  Nobody chooses an impossible path over a regrettable one.  Hint: if you want concurrency which is / can be resilient to "threads" being stopped, try Erlang: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_(programming_language)